# does FE Heroes treat weapons as skills?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I've been playing the hall of forms recently and I noticed a skill called phantom speed to give to one of my units. when a skill compares speed with an opponent, treat it as if the unit using it had +10 speed.
now I know of a unit's weapon that gives better stats when you're faster than your opponent, so I'm wondering how the game classifies weapons. are they technically skills, or something different entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Phantom Speed impacts any weapons that use speed caculations as well.

A good example of this is [Karla](https://gamepress.gg/feheroes/hero/karla), who states it right in her weapon [Vassal's Blade](https://gamepress.gg/feheroes/weapon-skills/vassals-blade):

> Accelerates Special trigger (cooldown count-1). If unit's Spd > foe's Spd, boosts damage dealt by 70% of difference between stats. (Maximum bonus of +7 damage. Combos with Phantom Spd.)

It works for newer units as well such as [Larcei](https://gamepress.gg/feheroes/hero/larcei), even though it is not explicitly stated (mostly due to how much text is already on Larcei's sword)